# Exporting full sql statement with data from mysql

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to export some data from mysql. When I run this:

```
mysql> SELECT     q.id thread_id, q.title, q.submitter_id user_id,     r.body, r.resolver_id staff_id, r.created_at created, r.updated_at updated FROM     responses r INNER JOIN questions q     ON r.question_id = q.id into outfile '/tmp/wintas.sql';
```

I get only the raw data. I would like sql with insert statements along with the data, similar to what I get in PHPMyAdmin using the export tab. Is there a way to do that from the mysql console?

Comment: You can try something like `SELECT CONCAT("INSERT INTO table(col_1, col_2, col_3, ...) VALUES(",col_1,",",col_2,",",col_3,...");") FROM table`

Comment: You should enable general_log for Mysql first.

`SET global general_log_file='/var/www/myhost/mysql.log'; SET global general_log = on; SET global log_output = 'file';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using a create table statement and the export the entire table. Here is the query I used:

```
CREATE TABLE thread_entry_responses SELECT
    q.id thread_id,
    q.title,
    q.submitter_id user_id,
    r.body,
    r.resolver_id staff_id,
    r.created_at created,
    r.updated_at updated,
    'M' AS type
FROM
    responses r
INNER JOIN questions q ON
    r.question_id = q.id;
```